# A numerical issue with solve.QP, the quadratic programming function in R

Tags: r, quadratic-programming

Let's say I have the following quadratic programming problem where the numbers are pretty big:

```
> require(quadprog)
> Q <- diag(c(34890781627, 34890781627, 34890781627, 34890781627, 34890781627))
> c <- c(133013236723, 29459621018, 31362634710, 24032348447, 23332381578)
> ( A <- t(kronecker(diag(1,5),as.matrix(c(1,-1)))) )
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1   -1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[2,]    0    0    1   -1    0    0    0    0    0     0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    1   -1    0    0    0     0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1   -1    0     0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    -1
> ( e <- rep(c(0,1),5) )
 [1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

The constraint is `Ax >= -e`: I am constraining all the variables to be within [0,1]. I guess because the numbers involved here are too huge, it causes some numerical issues. If I run

```
> solve.QP(Q,c,A,bvec=-e)$solution
```

I will get `Error in solve.QP(Q, c, A, bvec = -e) : constraints are inconsistent, no solution!`

When I try to divide everything by a large number to shrink these crazy numbers then the function is able to generate some outputs, but NOT CORRECT:

```
> 1E4*solve.QP(1E-8*Q,1E-4*c,A,bvec=-1E-4*e)$solution
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

I think the correct answer is

```
> w <- (1/diag(Q))*c
> w[w>1] <- 1
> w[w<0] <- 0
> w
[1] 1.0000000 0.8443382 0.8988803 0.6887879 0.6687263
```

I don't really need to QP here because `Q` matrix is diagonal, but I just want to use this as an illustration and get some advice on handling the numerical issues related to `solve.QP()`. Let's imagine that I have a dense `Q` matrix, what should I do in order to get the correct result?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, I just realized that I made a mistake when trying to shrink matrix `Q` and vector `c`.

`min x^T Q x /2 - c^T x` is equivalent to `min a * (x^T Q x /2 - c^T x)` with any positive `a`. So all I need to do is multiply both `Q` and `c` by the same small number, like the following:

```
> solve.QP(1E-8*Q,1E-8*c,A,bvec=-e)$solution
[1] 1.0000000 0.8443382 0.8988803 0.6887879 0.6687263
```

And this time it gives the correct result. Previously I was thinking of transforming `x = ay`, but my logic is incorrect. The correct way is the following:

`min x^T Q x /2 - c^T x` is equivalent to `min y^T (a^2*Q) y /2 - a*c^T y` with any positive `a`. And the constraint will also change accordingly to `Ay >= -e/a`. So you can also do

```
1E-4*solve.QP(1E-8*Q,1E-4*c,A,bvec=-1E4*e)$solution
[1] 1.0000000 0.8443382 0.8988803 0.6887879 0.6687263
```

---

### **Remaining Question**

In general, when should we consider this numerical issue and what is the optimal shrink size `a`? Or is there ways other than shrinking that can better solve this problem?